# How to cancel solr autowarm?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I imported many document through solr data import handler about 1,000,000 documents and do the one time commit manually(curl commit) after importing completely done.

Bad luck, commiting takes too long time, I stopped Solr server during incomplete committing, incomplete updating operations  might be kept in operation cache in somewhere.

Then I started Solr server again, **each uncommitted documents has been added and committed automatically after Solr server start**.  I don't know what is it. I guess it's autowarming after previous incomplete updating(add) operation.

Here is log after server start

> INFO  - 2014-11-30 12:33:31.077;
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update/ params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml}
>   {add=[2,268,5955,233495 (1486173619959627776)]} 0 1 INFO  - 2014-11-30
>   12:33:31.162; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor;
>   [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update/
>   params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml} {add=[2,445,9748,476937
>   (1486173620049805312)]} 0 0 INFO  - 2014-11-30 12:33:31.819;
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update/ params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml}
>   {add=[2,3,27,2724 (1486173620738719744)]} 0 1 INFO  - 2014-11-30
>   12:33:33.167; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor;
>   [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update/
>   params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml} {add=[2,996,17110,494309
>   (1486173622152200192)]} 0 0 INFO  - 2014-11-30 12:33:33.215;
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update/ params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml}
>   {add=[2,445,9745,511423 (1486173622202531840)]} 0 0 INFO  - 2014-11-30
>   12:33:33.640; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor;
>   [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update/
>   params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml} {add=[2,996,17111,516925
>   (1486173622648176640)]} 0 1 INFO  - 2014-11-30 12:33:33.860;
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update/ params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml}
>   {add=[2,286,6352,245986 (1486173622878863360)]} 0 0 INFO  - 2014-11-30
>   12:33:33.904; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor;
>   [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update/
>   params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml} {add=[2,826,15633,505508
>   (1486173622925000704)]} 0 0 INFO  - 2014-11-30 12:33:34.442;
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update/ params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml}
>   {add=[2,229,5196,197168 (1486173623489134592)]} 0 1 INFO  - 2014-11-30
>   12:33:34.514; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor;
>   [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update/
>   params={indent=on&version=2.2&wt=xml} {add=[2,386,8497,296860
>   (1486173623564632064)]} 0 0

These operations takes 1 month but not finished yet.

How to cancel it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably playing back the transaction log - check the tlog directory on disk. If you want to restart the indexing process with an empty index, remove everything under `data`.

Comment: I removed data directory and start Solr again.
Solr still continue adding document.

Comment: Well, then the client doing the indexing is still indexing. You'll have to stop the client that's submitting documents to your index.

Comment: The client has been stop adding document to Solr but Solr still continue adding something on startup.

Comment: Now I think it's transaction replay after large importing crashed.
Solr replay all transaction when startup to make sure no data lost after cash but it's very large data.

The transaction log file(in data/tlog/) is created for this case.
What is the transaction log generator? I guess it must be DataImportHandler. How to tell it to stop generating transaction log and stop replaying?

Comment: You can abort a running DataImportHandler by going to `http://<host>:<port>/solr/<collection>/dataimport?command=abort`.

Comment: Thank you, MatsLindh.
I aborted DIH but data still be addeded when Solr startup.
I think Solr DIH must wrire file(cache) somewhere and replay adding documents on Solr stratup.

Comment: Finally! I found https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#UNLOAD.
It's works perfectly.

When Solr core is loaded on startup, it replays update log from previous crashing to ensure no data lost. To stop the replaying process, just unload Solr core and create a new one.

I will remember till my life, don't do the one-time commit on large data import.

Thank you so much, MatsLindh. You are a good guy! ^___^